# mysql improve performmance by create new table

Tags: mysql

the code below is work but it take long time to run sometime the php code stop but it work well with mysql graphical tool (becase  it can wait) .  Are there any method to make it faster I use index in some column it help Are there any method to create table if I create table i think it will improve performance but this table it must be update maybe one a week what is the good practice please suggest

```
SELECT member.own, member.provincecode, province.PROVINCE_NAME, member.amphurecode,
    amphur.AMPHUR_NAME, member.Sname, member.Ssurname, member.Hno, member.Moo,
    member.Sex, member.tambol, member.dateofbirth, member.migratedate,
    Year( Current_Date( ) ) -  Year( member.dateofbirth ) AS y, 
    Year( Current_Date( ) ) - Year( member.migratedate ) AS m
FROM member
LEFT JOIN amphur ON ( member.amphurecode
COLLATE utf8_general_ci = amphur.AMPHUR_CODE )
LEFT JOIN province ON member.provincecode
COLLATE utf8_general_ci = province.PROVINCE_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

Collate is an expensive operation.  So assuming that `member` has more rows than`province`, try to collate the table with the smaller number of rows:

```
LEFT JOIN province ON member.provincecode
= province.PROVINCE_CODE COLLATE <collation of member.provincecode>
```

It would be even better to give all columns in all tables the same collation.